# How to kill a glassfish server in Windows?

Tags: windows, glassfish, glassfish-3

I tried to start a glassfishv3 server in my windows XP system with the command "asadmin start-domain". The start failed due to a timeout. When I try to start again I get an error saying that the port 4848 is allready in use by another process. When I try to stop the server with "asadmin stop-domain" I get the error that it is not running.

Any idea how to solve this deadlock? I cannot find a Windows process with the name glassfish or asadmin to kill.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The process will be `java.exe`

You can use one of the sysinternals tools, like tcpview.exe for example to see which program is actually using that port.

Answer (score 12):

Adding to Alexis' answer,

```
jps -v
```

will show you more about the java processes.  Note the pid.  You must have configured your [path](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Setting+the+JAVA_HOME+Variable+in+Windows) correctly for this to work.

Then do

```
taskkill /pid <pid>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `jps` to list all the Java processes on you machine. The GlassFish server main class is called `ASMain`